# How do I create two sign-up systems?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I wanted to create 2 signup options on the website. For example a student and teacher login methods. I want the form or model to extend and save it to the sqlite3 db. For example, if a student signs up the database would store a field `isteacher = False` and vise versa.

Also once they login is there a way to display two different dashboards based on the user?

Is there any guide or link to show me how to build this step by step? I have spent close to 8 hours figuring this out and i'm very close to giving up. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two sign up forms for such a thing if the students and teachers use the same credentials (e.g. username/email and password). Just simply add a selector for users to identify themselves. If they are not going to use same credentials, create a base view for common fields, then create separate signup views inheriting from that base view.

You need to extend User to add extra fields such as `is_teacher` (though I recommend you use CharField with choices so that you can add extra types of users in the future), there is a couple of ways of doing this [explained elaborately in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/), in your case setting up a custom user model via AbstractUser seems the best as I predict you will be extending that model further.

You can use UserPassesTestMixin or user_passes_test decorator to conditionally alter views for different types of users.